&$filter=substringof('ECG Spreadsheet.xlsx',File/Name) errors with "Column 'File' does not exist
Using SharePoint REST
 /_api/web/Lists/getbytitle('DPC Documents')/items?$expand=File&$select=File/Name

Works fine but
/_api/web/Lists/getbytitle('DPC Documents')/items?$expand=File&$select=File/Name&$filter=substringof('ATR Test 7.docx',File/Name)

Shows error:
"odata.error": {
        "code": "-2146232832, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en-US",
            "value": "Column 'File' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user."
        }

Any explanation? who can I search by file name?
Thanks

You can try this:
/_api/web/Lists/getbytitle('DPC Documents')/items?$expand=File&$select=File/Name&$filter=substringof('ATR Test 7.docx', FileLeafRef)

To filter by the file name, use the FileLeafRef field, which is the internal field name SharePoint uses to represent the file name.

I did not downvote but you could improve the answer by explaining why/how you think this solves the problem. P.S. @Replies in answers do nothing and are perceived as noise, and dashes do not go after colons.

In addition, please read [answer]. The tips listed there will help you write better answers that earn fewer downvotes.

@Ofer Gal did my above answer solved your issue? i tested it insid my tenant and it worked well

@microsoftdeveloperdesigner, if you really want feedback on this answer and thoughts about the downvote you can post on [meta], but that draws attention and often results in additional downvotes. I don't recommend it. SO is unlikely to ever add a "report downvote" feature for a number of reasons: votes are anonymous, they're allowed to be cast at users' discretion by design, etc. I know it's not fun to have an answer downvoted, but it happens to all of us. Try not to let it bother you too much.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
